# Magento2: How to add custom filter in categories / product

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to add a custom option to sort products in catalog -> categories -> [edit category) ---> tab: products?

I need to display here an additional attribute `category_path`. Is there any solution?

https://prnt.sc/rzbxx3

Comment: I couldn't understand your need. According to your screenshot, you are already in a category page. What kind of information are you trying to show?